# how to use `with open` in my own class method?

Tags: python, methods, file-handling

I want to define a class method to write directly to a file without explicitly closing the file. But if I return the object like so:

```
class sqlBuilder(object):
    ...   

    def save_sql_stat(self, file_n, mode = 'w'):
        try:
            with open(file_n, mode) as sql_out:
                return sql_out

        except IOError, IOe:
            print str(IOe)
```

I won't be able to do:

```
t = sqlBuilder(table)
out = t.save_sql_stat(sql_file)
out.write(...)
```

as I'm going to get a `ValueError`. What would be a good workaround without calling `out.close()`?

Comment: This may help: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. Indeed it sheds some light on the subject...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `closing` from `contextlib` and move the `with` statement outside...

```
from contextlib import closing

def save_sql_stat(self, file_n, mode='w'):
    try:
        return closing(open(file_n, mode))
    except IOError as e:
        print e.message

sql = SqlBuilder()
with sql.save_sql_stat('testing.sql') as sql_out:
    pass # whatever
```